Actualiza tu dependencia Play Core Maven a una versión compatible con Android 14
He recibido este mensaje de Google Play Console:

com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.8.0: 
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration 
You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.

Y he intentado seguir los pasos que muestran en el link, pero no entiendo bien que tengo que hacer, porque hablan sobre diversificar la librería, pero no comprendo que hace cada una o cual debería de poner.
Para ayudar, os dejo aquí mi build.gradle(app):
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", '"https://bla.bla.bla"'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", '"https://bla.bla.bla"'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    namespace 'bla.bla.bla'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0' //The app may crash with greater versions
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

    //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45"

    //Images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //Shimmer Effect
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //Maskara
    implementation 'com.github.santalu:maskara:1.0.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Google Map
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.5.0"

    // Biometrics
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"

    //Google auth
    // Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    // Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:13.0.0'
}


Hola. Simplemente cambia los valores de compileSdk y de targetSdk a 34. Crea un nuevo ..abb y lo subes a Play Console.

@A.Cedano, entonces, a pesar de que sale para migrar la dependencia, solamente con eso sería suficiente?

Es nuevo requerimiento para nuevas apps y actualización de las mismas en Google Play, debes crear tus apps definiendo:
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14)
En tu archivo app/build.gradle tienes actualmente lo siguiente:
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
    ...

Debes crear tus apps orientadas a android 14 (targetSdkVersion 34), por cierto, no debes usar minSdk y targetSdk, debes aumentar el versionCode para la nueva actualización, revisa la actualización que debes realizar:
android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
    ...

